# How to initilize JAXB with SAX

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshall an xml to java object using JAXB with SAX. I wrote this code in the constructor.

```
logger.debug("Initializing jaxb...");
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ProductInventory.class);
            jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            reader = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser().getXMLReader();
            EntityResolver entityResolver = new EntityResolver() {
                @Override
                public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId,
                        String systemId) {
                    return new InputSource(new StringReader(""));
                }
            };
            reader.setEntityResolver(entityResolver);
            logger.debug("Successfully initialized jaxb.");
        } catch (JAXBException | SAXException | ParserConfigurationException e) {
            logger.error("Exception while initializing JAXB", e);
        }
```

Is there any problem with the `reader` object when multiple requests come? Do I have to get a reference of `reader` always? I mean for every unmarshall action do I have to get a new xml reader?

Answer (score 0):

When using SAX with JAXB you leverage `UnmarshallerHandler` and not `Unmarshaller`.

```
UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();
reader.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
reader.parse(xml);
Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
```

`UnmarshallerHandler` is not thread safe so make sure you don't have threads sharing it.  You can parse multiple XML documents with the same `XMLReader`

Comment: Multiple threads will access the same code. So should I declare the unmarshallerHandler locally? I mean in the method to which the requests come