# What is the advantage of UnmarshallerHandler over Unmarshaller

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, sax

I am using JAXB with SAX. I am using Unmarshaller to unmarshall the data. It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20479521/1912429) that we have to use UnmarshallerHandler instead of Unmarshaller when combining JAXB with SAX. And then UnmarshallerHandler is not thread safe.

So should I wrap the unmarshalling code inside a synchronized block like below?

```
synchronized(this) {
    UnmarshallerHandler unmarshallerHandler = unmarshaller.getUnmarshallerHandler();
    reader.setContentHandler(unmarshallerHandler);
    reader.parse(xml);
    Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshallerHandler.getResult();
}
```

Now what is the advantage of using UnmarshallerHandler over Unmarshaller?

Answer (score 0):

`UnmarshallerHandler` was introduced to make it easy for people that need to use JAXB explicitly with a SAX parser (I.e there is some specific set up they need to do).  When you use `Unmarshaller` the JAXB impl is handling the parsing as it sees fit.

Unless you have a reason to use `UnmarshallerHandler` you shoul probably use `Unmarshaller`.

Comment: We are using SAX parser because we dont have any write operations. So we thought JAXB with SAX will do well and we did not want JAXB to decide what parsing technique to use. And we don't do any setup except setting a dummy EntityResolver on the XMLReader.